# How to send push notifications

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to add the ability to send push notifications out to users who have our app installed (yet to go to market).

I guess I will need to install a phonegap plugin that will look for updates on our server (or could be triggered from our server) but I'm struggling to find a good approach.

I have seen this:

https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin/tree/master/android-statusbar-notificaion

It allows phonegap to send a notification, but I don't know how I could send a remote message to the script to trigger a message.

Answer (score 3):

C2DM is deprecated and **GCM ( Google Cloud Messaging)** is used to implement your push notifications for Android App.

Answer (score 1):

In Android the technology of push notifications is called C2DM. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) is a tutorial for this.